# Do I need to put the throw inside the try catch block for it to be caught, using firebase function api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Do I need to put the throw inside the try catch block for it to be caught?
i am using firebase function api

```
// Checking that the user is authenticated.
if (!context.auth) {
    // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 
        'The function must be called while authenticated.');
} 

try {
    await updateCustomerAccount(context.auth.uid, customer.id)

    return {
        status: 200,
    };
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err as Error);
    return {
        error: err.errorInfo,
        status: 500,
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, from what I understand.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, no, you don't need your `throw` to be inside a try/catch.  If you want your function to terminate with a meaningful error in the calling code, you will need to allow that exception to propagate out of the top-level of the function so that it can be handled by the Cloud Functions SDK and converted into an HTTP error for the client to receive.  If you put it inside the try/catch, then the function won't generate the correct error code and message for the client app.

Also, if your callable function requires client authentication, then you should use the "unauthenticated" error code, not the "failed-precondition" code, as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.functions#functionserrorcode).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need to place the throw keyword inside the try block. The `try` `catch` block specifically only catches an error if it is inside the try block.

[To quote from MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)

> The throw statement throws a user-defined exception. Execution of the current function will stop (the statements after throw won't be executed), and control will be passed to the first catch block in the call stack. **If no catch block exists among caller functions, the program will terminate.**

Comment: That isn't true in this case.  The exception needs to propagate out of the function so that the SDK (Cloud Functions for Firebase) can capture it and send and appropriate response. Putting it in a try/catch will suppress the error, and the function won't work correctly. The OP should be showing more code to make this situation more clear.